# Llamar una función del main desde un modulo

Tags: python, funciones, modulos

Tengo una aplicación `Python` que usa módulos para manejar una base de datos, luego que me confirma que el registro fue realizado satisfactoriamente; quisiera que mi programa regresara a la función que abre el menú de opciones en el `main.py` para que el usuario decida si quiere registrar a alguien mas o loguearse. ¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Pd: el modulo está en un paquete dentro de la carpeta donde está el `main`:

Las funciones están aquí:

`C:\Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-WebBD\ProgramasPY\Proyectos\ProyectoPy\usuarios`

El `main.py` está aquí:

`C:\Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-Web-BD\ProgramasPY\Proyectos\ProyectoPy`

Comment: no tienes que hacer nada especial, cuando invocas a una función y esta termina, la ejecución siempre salta a la línea que sigue a su invocación. Si la invocaste desde el _main_, la ejecución siempre regresa al _main_.

Answer (score 0):

Para importar el módulo desde `main.py`:

```
import usuarios.modulo
```

Donde `modulo` es el nombre del archivo que contiene las funciones, y que está en la carpeta `usuarios`